# Poedit crashes after doing an catalogue update

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, poedit

I tried to update the catalogue from the sources. After finishing the updates poedit crashs. In the command-line-tool i get the following message:

```
b/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbusmenu-glib.so.4.0.13Aborted (core dumped)
```

I can see how poedit searches the source code for text-snippets. The progressbar works until 100%. Then poedit crashes without an error message.
I am using linux ubuntu. The source code is written in php.

Answer (score 1):

To me, I was helped by this guide: http://www.cssigniter.com/ignite/wordpress-poedit-translation-secrets/ which mentions the following headers for configuring the po file:

```
"X-Poedit-Basepath: .\n"
"X-Poedit-SearchPath-0: .\n"
"X-Poedit-SearchPath-1: ..\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please create a ticket at http://www.poedit.net/trac/newticket (preferably after reading http://www.poedit.net/trac/wiki/HowtoReportBugs - there's plenty of essential information missing here, such as the data files needed to reproduce it...).